# maven test | NoClassDefFoundException DirectFileOutputcommitter

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, amazon-s3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven surefire plugin for unit testing. One of the unit tests crash because of the following exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/DirectFileOutputCommitter`

Googling on this tells me that this class def is found in `amazon-s3.jar`, which resides in the `hadoop/lib` folder of my hadoop distribution. How do I get around this exception in unit tests?

Comment: Which hadoop distribution?